# The object passes through the walls

Tags: unity-game-engine

When the object named Player touches the wall, the collision takes place. But when I rotate the object and also want it to go forward it goes through the wall. What would be the reason ?

```
public float movementSpeed = 5.0f;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            transform.position -= transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, 150 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, - 150 * Time.deltaTime , 0);
        }
    }
```

I expect it not to go inside the object after I don't increase the width of the walls, but it doesn't.

Comment: Then you cant just teleport it by changing the transform you need to use its rigid body to move it so physics is properly applied

Comment: As @BugFinder said, you need to chose a movement method, or thought Rigidbody or thought Translate, not both

Comment: @BugFinder i'm a beginner, can you write a code example or more explanatory, please?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, changing transform.position will teleport your object and thus ignoring collision.

There are different ways of implementing a movement. You either have to add a Rigidbody or a CharacterController to your moving GameObject, if you want your object to collide. Here is an example for each - both methods should move your object forwards - so you still need to change the direction for complete movement.

Rigidbody:

```
private void MoveForward() {
 Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>;
 Vector3 direction = (transform.forward).normalized;
 float speed = 2;
 rb.AddForce(direction * speed)
}
```

CharacterController

```
private void MoveForward() {
    CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>;
    Vector3 direction = (transform.forward).normalized;
    float speed = 2f;
    controller.Move(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Edit: You will probably end up using the rigidbody, since you already have it inside your script - the variable initialisation shouldn't be inside the methods, I just did it for simplicity (maybe except the directions, if you want them to be relative to your camera)